# Regular expression ammendment

Tags: database, bash, grep

My regular expression needs tweaking in order to insert a newline after a match is found. Does anyone know how to achieve this please?

For example, when I run:

```
grep -A 2 -B 6 "^Errors: [1-9]" INC0108890.txt
```

This returns:

```py
Backup Set: UNIX-SSH\rmg-devweb-03\Backup of web code and configuration\rmg-asigra
Performed by: Backup Schedule: Weekdays Backup (8pm)
Started at: May 10, 2022, 8:00:01 PM
Finished at: May 10, 2022, 8:27:17 PM
Completion: Backup completed with errors.
Warnings: 0
Errors: 1
Backed up files: 1,462
Total amount: 97,617 KB
Backup Set: MySQL\rmg-db-04\Backup of MySQL Databases\rmg-asigra
Performed by: Backup Schedule: Weekdays Backup (8pm)
Started at: May 10, 2022, 8:00:01 PM
Finished at: May 10, 2022, 8:00:05 PM
Completion: Backup completed with errors and warnings.
Warnings: 1
Errors: 1
Backed up files: 0
Total amount: 0 KB
--
Backup Set: UNIX-SSH\rmg-sysint-11\Backup of /server\rmg-asigra
Performed by: Backup Schedule: Weekdays Backup (8pm)
Started at: May 10, 2022, 8:00:01 PM
Finished at: May 10, 2022, 8:17:13 PM
Completion: Backup completed with errors.
Warnings: 0
Errors: 87
Backed up files: 248
Total amount: 3,752,207 KB
```

However, I desire an output as follows if anyone can advise please:

```py
Backup Set: UNIX-SSH\rmg-devweb-03\Backup of web code and configuration\rmg-asigra
Performed by: Backup Schedule: Weekdays Backup (8pm)
Started at: May 10, 2022, 8:00:01 PM
Finished at: May 10, 2022, 8:27:17 PM
Completion: Backup completed with errors.
Warnings: 0
Errors: 1
Backed up files: 1,462
Total amount: 97,617 KB

Backup Set: MySQL\rmg-db-04\Backup of MySQL Databases\rmg-asigra
Performed by: Backup Schedule: Weekdays Backup (8pm)
Started at: May 10, 2022, 8:00:01 PM
Finished at: May 10, 2022, 8:00:05 PM
Completion: Backup completed with errors and warnings.
Warnings: 1
Errors: 1
Backed up files: 0
Total amount: 0 KB

Backup Set: UNIX-SSH\rmg-sysint-11\Backup of /server\rmg-asigra
Performed by: Backup Schedule: Weekdays Backup (8pm)
Started at: May 10, 2022, 8:00:01 PM
Finished at: May 10, 2022, 8:17:13 PM
Completion: Backup completed with errors.
Warnings: 0
Errors: 87
Backed up files: 248
Total amount: 3,752,207 KB
```

Comment: In the first output you show there is only one `--` after `Total amount: 0 KB`. Are you sure you do not have others?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes sir, the output was not consistent, within my windows subsystem for linux ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 2):

`--group-separator=$'\n'` should do the trick.